# Devolver una entidad

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framewor app windowsw forms, necesito devolver una enbtidad para eso estoy llamando al método Single pero no se como utilizarlo 
[image: Single]

Lo que intento implementar si existe me devuelva una entidad y no existe me devuelva un null, en otras palabras si existe me devuelve la entidad y hago update y si no existe me devuelve nulo y hago create.

```
public void Create(Talla entity)
    {
        if(_tallaRepository.Single()
        //if (_tallaRepository.Existe(entity.TallaId))
            _tallaRepository.Update(entity);
        else
            _tallaRepository.Create(entity);
    }
```

Este método me devuelva una entidad en vez de true o false

```
public bool Existe(int codigo)
    {
        int result = Context.Tallas.Where(x => x.TallaId == codigo).Count();
        if (result == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pero para validar si existe no usas el Single() tienes que crear un metodo nuevo que use el Any() de linq

```
public class RepositoryBase
{
    public bool Exist(Expresion<Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return contexto.Any(predicate);
    }
}
```

La idea es que definas algo como ser

```
if(_tallaRepository.Exist(x=> x.Id == entity.Id)){
   //aqui actualizas
}
```

debes definir como predicado como valida si existe la entidad, se usa para esto el id

Comment: Gracias, Leandro pude actualizar como recomendo Sergio Parra, lo anlizare en el profiler, me lo vas a tener que traducir, jajaja